# Spring Security, не происходит redirect на Access denied page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Возможно должен быть и не редирект, а просто отображение страницы.
Особо никаких настроек, ничего нет, использую Java based configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error");
    }
}
```

Страница /error, открывается, всё ок, доступ на все ссылки api/** закрыты, но вместо редиректа на /error я получаю стандартное окошко 403 Tomcat'а.

```
@Controller
public class Pages {
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String index() {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

При этом если указать страницу логина через `.formLogin`, то начинает работать редирект на страницу логина. И если указать в `formLogin` мой error, всё будет работать. Но не `exceptionHandling`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался. Было тяжко, потому что в документации информация разбросана хаотично и сколько не читай, а всё равно создал точку останова и начал разбирать шаг за шагом, попутно заглядывая в доку.

Причина вот в чем была. accessDeniedPage открывается при обработке `AccessDeniedException` (логично, не так ли?), которое выбрасывается где-то в глубине объекта `accessdecisionmanager`. То есть Authentication тут уже получена и все объекты аутентификации не при делах. Переход на страницу осуществляется когда Пользователь был успешно распознан одним из цепочки `AuthenticationProvider's` в `AuthenticationManager`, но пользователю не хватило прав для доступа к странице.

Но когда нет каких либо источников аутентификации (например логин + пароль для `UsernamePasswordAuthentication` или данных в куки для `RememberMe`, смотря чего навключать) вовращается `BadCredentialsException`, которое является потомком `AuthenticationException`. Обрабатывать его нужно отдельно с помощью `.authenticationEntryPoint(...)` (кто придумал такое название? У меня лично вообще не ассоциируется с тем для чего можно применять это) вместо `.accessDeniedPage(...)`.